# ssh no key found when used with appleboy ssh actions in Github actions for Ubuntu

Tags: git, ubuntu, ssh, github-actions, cicd

I am working on my cicd flow with Github actions, and deploying a docker containers on Ubuntu server. Original server authentication was with password. I later added SSH keys generated using PuttyGen on windows, and enabled SSH authentication on Ubuntu. I am able to login using SSH key using putty, so SSH key auth is working fine.

However, when I try to deploy using Github actions using appleboy/ssh-action it fails with an error message

```
ssh.ParsePrivateKey: ssh: no key found
ssh: handshake failed: ssh: unable to authenticate, attempted methods [none], no supported methods remain
```

Here is the step using appleboy

```
name: Deploy project on Ubuntu
        uses: appleboy/ssh-action@v1.0.3
        with:
          host: ${{secrets.SSH_HOST}}
          port: ${{secrets.SSH_PORT}}
          username: ${{secrets.SSH_USERNAME}}
          key: ${{secrets.SSH_KEY}}
```

I verified the key exists in secrets with correct name, and it works when I test it to copy files to the ubuntu server. But when using appleboy it doesn't work.

What could be wrong? Should I need to change the key format or something else is wrong?

Comment: Is `secrets.SSH_KEY` public or private key? Must be private. Is it the content of the entire file? There're many lines in the file.

Comment: Yes, its private file and there are many lines in the file. I stored entire file as secret

Comment: I'm also having the same issue. I ensured that it is indeed the private key and copied the entire content and stored it in repository secrets. I only get the first error: `ssh.ParsePrivateKey: ssh: no key found`.